# Use user declared string as method

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to give a user an option which string he can use?

I have an object:
myObject which has 3 string

```
myObject.string1
myObject.string2
myObject.string3
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var whichString = "string1";

myObject.whichString 
myObject.(whichString)
myObject.[whichString]
```

None of the above works.
Is there a way to do it, please?

Comment: I assumed your two last lines are the result of lazy copy-pasting but should read `myObject.(whichString)` and `myObject[whichString]` , right ?

Comment: Hey, @RomainVALERI you don't need to judge. I'm a beginner user. If you want to help. Just help. Thanks

Comment: I'm very sorry, I never wanted to shame you by using the term *lazy*, we're ALL guilty of this once in a while, and I clumsily wanted to refer to it as a minor typing mistake, not a reasoning mistake.

Comment: Ok, no problem & thanks for the help. It's working now :-)

Answer (score 2):

If your `myObject` object is created like this :

```
var myObject = {
  string1: "abc",
  string2: "def",
  string3: "xyz"
}
```

Then

```
var whichString = "string1";

alert(myObject[whichString]);// this will alert "abc"
```

should be fine.

Comment: @Andreas Hmmm, now you're making me doubt... but to be fair, we don't know much about how `myObject` is constructed here.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the context of myObject I was assuming.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I've edited, thanks for your insight :-)